# How to print all lines after last occurrence of a 'specific word' in text file

Tags: java, file, line

I am working on a file using java, where i want to print all lines after last occurrence of a word. For example :

```
> </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>    
  <Tabla1>
  <NUM>1</NUM>
  </Tabla1>
  <Tabladf>
  <NUM>2</NUM>
  </Tabladf>
```

So, in above example all data should be printed after `</xs:schema>`

Code what i used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\Project\\LM2\\supw.xml"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("</xs:schema>"))
                System.out.println(line);
        }

    }
}
```

Please tell what changes should i do, to get correct output.

Comment: Where you are going wrong is you have only printed a line containing the word. Simplest approach will be to read all lines to a `String` then print all after the word using `String .substring()`. `myString.substring(myString.indexOf("</xs:schema>" + 12 ,myString.length()))`

Comment: Are you sure you're not working on valid XML? Because that would give the answer a much different direction.

Answer (score 0):

First, read all of the text and put it in a string variable.

```
String s = "> </xs:element>\n" +
        "  </xs:schema>    \n" +
        "  <Tabla1>\n" +
        "  <NUM>1</NUM>\n" +
        "  </Tabla1>\n" +
        "  <Tabladf>\n" +
        "  <NUM>2</NUM>\n" +
        "  </Tabladf>"; // instead of writing a string literal, you will read all the lines and put it here
```

Then, use a regex to match the string and find the end index of the last match of the regex:

```
int index = 0;
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("</xs:schema>\\s*\\n").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) { // keep finding new matches until there is not any
    index = m.end();
}
```

Then, call `substring(index)` and you will get your expected result!

```
 System.out.println(s.substring(index));
```

Comment: my xml file contains around 3500 line,, so i doubt that this will be an efficient way of doing.

Comment: @BleedCode I see. I'll keep this answer in case someone else finds this useful.

Comment: No This is not efficient because  org.w3c.dom library use Stream(Thread for improve efficiency).

Answer (score -1):

If you really only want to print lines after a specific line, you can't output anything before you encountered the last line of the file or that line might still come up later. So you have to store what you need to print.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\Project\\LM2\\supw.txt"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("</xs:schema>")) {
                // print everything after this line, right?
                lines.clear();
            } else {
                lines.add(line);
            }
        }
    }
    // now the file is finished, can print
    lines.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is easy for a person new to Java to understand. You haven't provided an explanation of what your loop does, and the last line (lambda expression) is definitely beyond the scope of an introductory Java class.

Comment: @gparyani I have provided an explanation what my loop does ("you have to store what you need to print"). And this is not an introductory Java class site, even if this question is relatively basic; if OP has a problem he can ask. If he doesn't know the lambda expression yet he learned something additional.

Comment: The OP said in a comment on another answer that he'd rather not store the file in memory, because it's very large.

Comment: @gparyani well under that condition it's just not possible in one pass. I'd find a side condition added in a comment to another answer a poor reason to downvote an answer though tbh.